# how do i fix a laggy code? I just started learning how to use OpenCV in Python and I'm not sure how to get my live video feed to run smoothly

Tags: python, opencv, keypress, video-capture, lag

Hello stackoverflow community. I think you folks are prolly the only ones I can turn to for expert advice or help for apart from chatGPT(but that's not really reliable is it). I started learning how to use OpenCV in Python as an absolute Novice about 3 months ago. I was able to create a program that was able to do what I needed it to do in terms of actual functionality. up till a certain point the code ran pretty smoothly and showed the live video feeds or subtraction feeds smooth and without lag. but as i started adding more functionality to it the live Video feeds and subtraction feeds got progressively laggier and the detection of keypresses got progressively slower. is there by any chance a way to keep the feeds running smoothly whilst also maintaining functionality? I don't really know anything about code optimization or how it is done. if you could perhaps provide me with some tips or guidelines on how to get the loop itself and the feeds and keypress-detection to run smoothly I would really appreciate it as it would enable me to learn a lot as a beginner :). I have integrated the relevant variables already before the while loop itself but here is the code snippet that performs the functionalities(i.e. the while loop) in the program:

```
while True:
        # Read a frame from the video capture object
    ret, live = camera.read()  #read live feed
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    #bg=None
    # If the frame was successfully read
    if ret:
        # Display the frame if the 'r' key is pressed
        key=cv2.waitKey(1)  & 0xFF #to run live feed smoothly
        if key == ord('7'):
            exit()
        if key==ord('1'):
          show_notification("already in Native mode")  
        if show_video:
          cv2.imshow('angio sim', gray)  #create a blank window
        
          # Wait for a key press and check if the 'r' key is pressed
          key=cv2.waitKey(1)  & 0xFF #for making the live feed run smoothly
        if key == ord('r'): #if condition for keypress r
          show_video = True  #change value of flag          
        elif not keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
          show_video = False
          key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key==ord('s'):
                 target = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
                 location = (
                 target.left,
                 target.top,
                 target.width,
                 target.height
                 )
                 image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=location)
                 now = datetime.now() #get current date and time
                 dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
                 #image.show()
                 filename1 = 'Screenshot_' + dt_string  +'.jpg'
                 image=image.save(filename1)
                 show_notification("Screenshot saved, please view in folder Dsa Simulator")
                 # Get the handle of the window by its title
                 key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key==ord('2'):
                  # To show a notification, call the function with the desired text
                  show_notification("Roadmap Mode. Press r until satisfactory background picture is formed, then d for starting the subtraction and actual roadmap.")
                  flag=Roadmap
                  key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                  # initialize a frame counter
                  count = 1
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        acc = gray.astype('float')  
                # Loop through the frames in the video              
        while flag==Roadmap:
                
                key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                # Read the next frame
                ret, frame = camera.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                #acc = gray.astype('float')  
                # Check for user input
                key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('1'):  # Escape key
                    show_notification("back to Native mode!")
                    flag=False
                if key==ord('7'):
                    exit()    
                if key == ord('r'):
                 
                 # Compute the minimum blend of the current frame and the accumulator
                 acc = np.minimum(acc, gray.astype('float'))

                 # Increment the frame counter
                 count += 1

                 # Convert the blended frame to an unsigned 8-bit integer
                 blended = acc.astype('uint8')

                 # Display the blended frame
                 cv2.imshow("angio sim", blended)
                 #key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('d'):
                 # Compute the difference between the current frame and the blended frame
                 result = cv2.subtract(gray, blended)
                 # Set the result to white
                 result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
                 result[np.where((result == [255, 255, 255]).all(axis=2))] = [0, 0, 255]
                 # Set the background to light gray
                 background = np.zeros_like(result)
                 background.fill(192)
                 # Combine the background and the result
                 output = cv2.addWeighted(background, 0.5, result, 0.5, 0.0)
                 # Display the difference frame
                 cv2.imshow("angio sim", output)
                if key==ord('2'):
                 show_notification("Roadmap mode reset")
                 blended=None
                 continue  # jump back to the beginning of the while loop    
                else: 
                 key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                
                 
                if key==ord('3'):
                 show_notification("DSA mode")
                 flag=DSA
                 #key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key==ord('3'):
                 show_notification("DSA mode")
                 flag=DSA
                 ret, live = camera.read()  #read live feed
                 gray = cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                 #key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        #for recording video of aufnahme
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        filename2 = 'output_{}.avi'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
        # Set the screen size
        screen_size = (1920, 1080)
        fps = 2
        
        # Create a video writer object
        video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename2, fourcc, fps, screen_size)
        
        while flag==DSA:           
                 ret, live = camera.read()  #read live feed
                 gray = cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                 key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                 Name_DSA=filename2
                  # Get the current screen frame
                 screen_frame = pyautogui.screenshot()
                 

                 # Convert the screen frame to a numpy array
                 screen_frame_np = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

                 if ret:
                     # Display the frame if the 'r' key is pressed
                     #key=cv2.waitKey(1)  & 0xFF #to run live feed smoothly
                     if key ==ord('7'):
                      exit()
                     if key==ord('1'):  
                         show_notification("Native mode ")
                         flag=False
                         key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                     if key==ord('s'):
                          path = r'C:/Users/skhandelwal/Desktop/Dsa Simulator'
                          os.chdir(path)
                          target = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
                          location = (
                          target.left,
                          target.top,
                          target.width,
                          target.height
                          )
                          image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=location)
                          now = datetime.now() #get current date and time
                          dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
                          #image.show()
                          filename1 = 'Screenshot_DSA_' + dt_string  +'.jpg'
                          image=image.save(filename1)
                          show_notification("Screenshot saved, please view in folder Dsa Simulator")                        
            
                     if show_video:
                         cv2.imshow('angio sim', gray)  #create a blank window
                         #key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                         # Wait for a key press and check if the 'r' key is pressed
                         key=cv2.waitKey(15)  & 0xFF #for making the live feed run smoothly
                     if key == ord('r'): #if condition for keypress r
                         show_video = True  #change value of flag
                         bg=None
                         key_pressed=True
                         now = datetime.now() #get current date and time
                         dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
                         filename = 'Backgroundat1fps_'+ dt_string +'.jpg'
                         #key=cv2.waitKey(1)           
                     if key_pressed and  not keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
                         bg=gray
                         #print(bg.shape)
                         font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                         now_without_ms= now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                         cv2.putText(bg, str(now_without_ms), (20, 40), font, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                         maske=live
                         gray_mask=cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                         key_pressed=False# to freeze live feed
                     if key==ord('3'):
                         show_notification("Already in DSA mode, background reset successfully, please take new Background.")  
                         flag=DSA                              
                     if key==ord('2'):
                         show_notification("Roadmap mode")
                         flag =Roadmap
                     elif not keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
                         show_video = False
                     if key == ord('d'):
                         diff = cv2.absdiff(gray, bg)
                         inverted_diff = cv2.bitwise_not(diff)
                         diff_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(diff, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)
    
                         # create a light gray background image with the same shape as inverted_diff
                         background = np.full(inverted_diff.shape, 0, dtype=np.uint8)
    
                         # blend the inverted_diff and background images
                         alpha = 0.8
                         blended_image = cv2.addWeighted(inverted_diff, alpha, background, 1-alpha, 0)
    
                         cv2.imshow('angio sim', blended_image)
                         # Write the current screen frame to the output video
                         screen_frame = pyautogui.screenshot()

                         # Convert the screen frame to a numpy array
                         screen_frame_np = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

                         video_writer.write(screen_frame_np)
                     if key == ord('8'):
                            # Open the saved video file
                            saved_video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename2)
                            saved_video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
                            frame_count = 0


                            while True:
                                # Read the next frame from the saved video file
                                ret, frame5 = saved_video.read()
                                if not ret:
                                    break

                                cv2.imshow('angio sim', frame5)

                                # Wait for a short time between frames
                                key = cv2.waitKey(25)

                                if key == 27:
                                  exit()

                            frame_count += 1

                            # End of video file
                            saved_video.release()
                            print("End of video file ({} frames)".format(frame_count))

                            print('L_released')
                     else:
                      key=cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Step 1: [edit] your question, remove all the irrelevant meta-commentary, and use paragraphs to turn the wall of text into a legible description of the problem. | Step 2: Refactor that code into something maintainable, and easy to reason with. A ~250 line loop body with ~7 levels of indentation isn't. Get rid of all the commented out statements while you're at it. | That said, you really ought to consolidate all those ~20 `cv2.waitKey` calls. With 1 millisecond delay times you use, it's a lottery which one will capture the keypress event, and it makes the logic like spaghetti.